# How to write a sort operation that can handle back event in navigationconroller?

Tags: iphone, xcode

How can I write a sort operation or another operation that doesn't stop to handle my touch events? For example, when I touch Back in UINavigationController, the app immediately goes back and releases the UIViewController.

Comment: Don't understand what your asking for. Shownig us the code you have that is'nt working could help!

Comment: only god knows..!! what are you trying to ask..!!

Comment: Sorry for my bad question. I send http request and when it finished I sort received data. Sorting operation duration is 4 seconds and I want that Back button in UINavigationContoller working during sort operation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your sort operation into the background:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^(void) {
 // you sort operation here

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
         // you updated UI operation here
     });
});
```

Then you can release other code, but be careful to touch something outside

Comment: Thanks. But when I run with this changes app crash on staring.